# Array of instances in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, instance

I need to store an array of instances of a specific class. Which I can then access from a class method anywhere. (kind of like lots of singletons)

At first I thought to just have a static NSMutableArray and in `init` add `self` to the array and in `dealloc` remove it from the array. But because NSArrays retain their objects, dealloc will never be reached.

I was hoping there would be a function in something like runtime.h, to get all instances of a class, just as you can get a list of all classes.

So how can I keep track of all instances of a specific that are in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create a trivial non-retaining array:

```
NSMutableArray * nonRetainingArray = (NSMutableArray*)CFArrayCreateMutable(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider `NSObject * array[3];`?

Comment: @daniel, But then there can only be 3 instances, is there a dynamically sizing c array?

Comment: You can always malloc/new it.

Comment: As I said in my answer:  NSPointerArray.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter if, when your application terminates, there are still lots of singleton objects which haven't been deallocated.  Since your array is a singleton, there's no problem with it not going away.

The only problem is whith the objects in the array.  If you add them to the array in `-init`, you can't remove them from the array in `-dealloc` because `-dealloc` will never be called.  If you just want to keep a reference to all of the live objects of a certain type, you could use an [NSPointerArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPointerArray) which is like an array but doesn't retain its elements.

Comment: The instances themselves aren't singletons, they should be created and destroyed like ordinary instances. I just need to be able to access all instances of this class from anywhere in my program

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, that is why I am suggesting NSPointerArray.